# Is it possible to lock a bucket for writes?

Tags: locking, google-cloud-storage, file-locking

I am looking to develop a sync solution on google cloud storage. Does GCS offer a locking mechanism so a bucket won't be written to concurrently, and if so, what protections against deadlocks does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to lock a Google Cloud Storage bucket or object.

You can, however, use an object's generation, metageneration and preconditions to achieve optimistic concurrency. See [Generation Numbers and Preconditions](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions) for details.